# Pattern (formatting) for String expression

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using *iReport* for designing of reports. I need to format a string such as *`xxxxxxxxxxx`* to *`xxx xxx xxx xxx`*. I am able to specify pattern for date, number, time and currency.

But how do I do this for a string? Can anyone provide me an insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using scriptlet. Thanks for the reply will try your method also.

```
public String formatNum(String tabn) {

    String num = tnum;

    String temp, t1, t2, t3, t4;

    temp = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.leftPad(num, 11, '0');

    t1 = temp.substring(0, 2);
    t2 = temp.substring(2, 5);
    t3 = temp.substring(5, 8);
    t4 = temp.substring(8, 11);

    num = t1 + " " + t2 + " " + t3 + " " + t4;

    return num;
}
```

And write this method in a class which extends JRDefaultScriptlet class and export it as jar and then add this to your iReport's Classpath. Now add it as scriptlet and then you can use this method to format to the above required format in your report.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a regular expression with replacements:

Let's say that your data is called `$F{field}` and it is a `java.lang.String`, and the current value is "0123456789ab" and you want it to be "012 345 678 9ab". Try this as your text field value:

```
$F{field}.replaceAll("^(...)(...)(...)(...)$", "$1 $2 $2 $4")
```

If you want something more generic, you can get cuter with your regular expression and replacement. For example, if you always want triplets but you don't care how many there are, you can do:

```
$F{field}.replaceAll("(...)", "$1 ").trim()
```

Note that the `trim` will be required because the final triplet will have en extra space appended to it.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I solved this by using scriptlet. Thanks for the reply will try your method also.